# Checkboxes and text doesn't want to show the value

Tags: php, mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Talenquiz2</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php

if (isset($_GET["controleer"]))
  {
  $vraag = $_GET["vraag"];
  $juistantwoord = $_GET["juistantwoord"];
  $foutantwoord1 = $_GET["foutantwoord1"];
  $foutantwoord2 = $_GET["foutantwoord2"];
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("dbproject", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblquizvragen");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  if ($row['vraag'] == $vraag)
    {
    if ($row['juistantwoord'] == $juistantwoord)
     {
     echo "Juist!<br />";
     }
    else
      {
      echo "Fout!<br />";
      }
    }
  }
  mysql_close($con);
  echo "\n<hr />\n";
  }

$aantalvragen=1;
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbproject", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblquizvragen WHERE id='". $aantalvragen . "';");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

The program is a quiz, it asks 5 questions with 3 chckbox 1 is corect and 2 are incorrect.

```
for ($aantalvragen=1; $aantalvragen<=5; $aantalvragen++)
 {
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 }
```

her i lin

```
$vraag = $row['vraag'];
$juistantwoord = $row['juistantwoord'];
$foutantwoord1 = $row['foutantwoord1'];
$foutantwoord2 = $row['foutantwoord2'];


mysql_close($con);
?>




<form>
```

It doensn't show the values of the rows in my browser it shows only an open text and an open checkbox.

```
<input type="text" name="vraag" value="<?php echo $vraag; ?>" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="juistantwoord" value="<?php echo $juistantwoord; ?>" /><br     />
<input type="checkbox" name="foutantwoord1" value="<?php echo $foutantwoord1; ?>" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="foutantwoord2" value="<?php echo $foutantwoord2; ?>" /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Controleer je antwoord" name="controleer" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect for fetching from the db

```
for(...) {
   $row = mysql_fetch_array(...);
}
```

You simply loop over 5 lines of results, regardless of how many there may be, and assign the row array to $row... but do so for EVERY row without ever using them. So you end up trashing the first `n-1` rows and come out of the loop with only row `n` saved.

If you're wrong with how many rows of data you're expecting, your 5-item loop may have only a 4-item result set to deal with, and the final row `$row1` value will be the boolean FALSE that msyql_fetch returns when there's no more data.

Try something like this instead:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo ..... your stuff here ...
}
```

Far more reliable, doesn't depend on there being a known number of rows available, and will not output anything if there's no data at all.